# How to create a local database using JSON and JavaScript for webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, web

I need to develop a simple webapp with a login system, users and data saved to each one of those users, with no knowlege of PHP or Data bases, only HTML, JavaScript/JQuery and JSON.

I must be able to sign up, log in and save some data (it's an online store, i must be able to save purchases historic, list of avourite products, user preferences, etc), all this locally only.

What is the best way to do this?

Security issues are not relevant.

I'm sorry for the bad english, I'm not a native speaker.

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localstorage` to use it as a db engine, but it is really limited,

You can use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup/Usando_IndexedDB) to use a localdb for you webapp.

Than will help you yo achieve your goals.

Remember that only moderm browser support IndexedDB, so you can check if your browser support it, else you can send a message for the user, to update the browser or fallback to `localstorage`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using PHP, i would Recommend looking into using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) for the server-side part of your app. Node.js is written with javascript, so it will be relatively easy to learn.

On the website, you can use HTML forms to send data to the server using JSON. The other parts of your app can be built using HTML, CSS and javascript.

Although i recommend using SQL, there are other ways to store data like using MongoDB.